# Cannot create AWS ServiceCatalogProduct using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-service-catalog

I am trying to create a ServiceCatalogProduct using a cloudformation json file like below:

```
> aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name hmm --template-body file:///tmp/1.json
```

My cfn template file (1.json) looks like shown below. I have confirmed that the template file is valid. When I try to create the stack I get a generic error message "Failed to create following Provisioning Artifacts: [ pa-jas39ah3a1d ]". What am I missing?

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "Product": {
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "",
                "Name": "redis-DEV-shu-cluster",
                "Owner": "shubham",
                "ProvisioningArtifactParameters": [
                    {
                        "Description": "Time created (UTC): 2020-11-04T04:13:42.897954",
                        "DisableTemplateValidation": "true",
                        "Info": {
                            "LoadTemplateFromURL": "https://s3:amazonaws.com/my-artifact-bucket-name/ag28ajo1-1ef1-47c9-80dc-7tuha718"
                        },
                        "Name": "1.0.0"
                    }
                ],
                "SupportEmail": ""
            },
            "Type": "AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error in the "events" tab in cloudformation console:

[image]

Comment: What about the template from `LoadTemplateFromURL`?

Comment: I already extracted that template and confirmed that that is valid and I am able to run that manually with cloudformation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely reason is spelling mistake:

```
https://s3:amazonaws.com/my-artifact-bucket-name/ag28ajo1-1ef1-47c9-80dc-7tuha718
```

it should be (note `s3.`, not `s3:`):

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-artifact-bucket-name/ag28ajo1-1ef1-47c9-80dc-7tuha718
```

Comment: aargh - and I spent a good 4 days trying to "debug" what I was doing wrong.. haha